# How to fix `SyntaxError: Unexpected token export` when using fabric-ui-foundation

Tags: typescript, node-modules, office-ui-fabric

1. I have some common TS library that uses `@uifabric/foundation` npm package.
   This library exposes some React components, that are based on uifabric code style and patterns.
2. There is also a TS/React/Redux project that consumes this library (using npm link). Compiles and works without problems.
3. The project comtains some test scenarios. Used stack: `mocha, enzyme, sinon, chai`. Compiles without problems, but when executing mocha tests I constantly get

```
[sharedlibpath]\node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\index.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { export * from './Async';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

Checked the output js file from component that is failing and it's the line 
`var lib_1 = require("@uifabric/utilities/lib");`

Can anybody shed some light on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Seems problem with module resolution. Dofferent for compilation and different for test run.
Solution for `jest` is described in MS Fabric Wiki: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Fabric-6-Release-Notes

But then when my components import not from `@uifabric/utilities/lib` but `@uifabric/utilities/lib-commonjs` this leads to: ["Cannot find module" when running unit tests on node.js with react as peer dependency in common package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57786415/cannot-find-module-when-running-unit-tests-on-node-js-with-react-as-peer-depen)