# "Cannot find module" when running unit tests on node.js with react as peer dependency in common package

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, webpack, office-ui-fabric

I have following app structure:

- `Application A`
- `Application B`
- `Common package`

Now `Application A` and `B` have in `package.json` the common package added:

```
{
  dependencies: {
      "commonPackage": "file:../../../commonPackage"
  }
}
```

both apps use React, as well as the common package, all had React added with `npm`, and it worked, before we started to use react hooks.

Because when we started, we got an [Invalid Hook Call Warning](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html) due to having "more than one copy of React", so to avoid that, in the common package, the react dependency was moved to `peerDependencies` so that the react instance from the app is used and not from the package.

It works great in the browser when we run both apps `A` and `B`, but when I run my `mocha` tests in the console, I get:

```
ERROR in ../commonPackage/~/@uifabric/utilities/lib/customizations/Customizer.js
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react' in 'D:\myProject\commonPackage\node_modules\@uifabric\utilities\lib\customizations'
```

this is from the `office-ui-fabric-react` package we use, but it seems like a more general issue with dependency resolution.

Project is in TypeScript, we use `webpack` for the compilation of the app for the browser, and `tsc` to compile for the unit tests.

I found some answers, suggesting to `npm link` react in the common package to the react package in the application `node_modules`, but it seems wrong, since the common package is used by two applications, it would solve the issue only for one.

Comment: If your `mocha` tests are in `commonPackage` and you need React for test purposes in common, you could it as `devDependency`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case above we finally came to a solution which was

- adding back react as devDependency to `Common package`
- using `esm` package to help our test runs understand es6 module export/import that came with `fabric` package. Just using `mocha --require esm ...`
- ejecting and adding alias to `webpack.config.js` in `Application`

  ```
      alias: {
          'react': path.resolve('./node_modules/react')
      }
  ```

Application A, B and hooks work now.

Comment: Yea! This worked for me.  I was only using fabric (so far) in my applications, not the common package, so I didn't need the `--require esm` part, but this last step, adding the `alias` to the `resolve` section of my `webpack.config.js` is what got me working again.

Comment: For me this one was the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64365016/jest-cannot-find-module-react-and-other-node-modules